# slds-size Not Working Properly For All Elements

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, slds-grid

I have the following HTMLin a Lightning Web Component:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap"> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerFee" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Corner Fee:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" formatter="currency" value={cornerFee} disabled ></lightning-input></div>                              
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerQty" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="# of Corners:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" value={cornerQty} ></lightning-input></div>                              
    </div> 
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerCost" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Corner Cost:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" formatter="currency" value={cornerCost} disabled ></lightning-input></div>                              
    </div>                              
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Select" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Letter Code" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Description" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Price/SqFt" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Booth #" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Depth" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Width" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Total SqFt" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
        <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Total Booth Cost" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first three elements in the grid, the `lightning-input` components, size as expected (via the `slds-size_1-of-3` class) relative to the containing `<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">` grid.

However, the remaining elements do not.  Rather, they all get squished to the left of the div:

[image]

Below is the corresponding HTML that's rendered:

[image]

For the column headings, I originally had straightforward HTML like so:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center"><b>Select</b></div>
```

I hoped using a lightning component like `lightning-formatted-text` instead would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Also, as you can see in the first screenshot, further below in my LWC, I have another grid containing 9 `lightning-input` and they size just fine.

Finally, if I remove a column and use `slds-size_1-of-8`, everything is sized properly.  I only discovered this problem when I wanted to add a column and changed the class for all the elements to `slds-size_1-of-9`.

Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

Below is the entirety of the LWC's HTML (I also tried with and without `slds-align_absolute-center` for the column headings as I did for the lower `lightning-input` components):

```
<template>
    <div if:true={loading} class="slds-is-relative">
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Add Booths" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    <template if:true={visible}>        
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" alternative-text="Click to Close" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Booths</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <article class="slds-card">                        
                        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                            <div if:true={loading} class="slds-is-relative">
                                <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap"> 
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerFee" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Corner Fee:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" formatter="currency" value={cornerFee} disabled ></lightning-input></div>                              
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerQty" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="# of Corners:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" value={cornerQty} ></lightning-input></div>                              
                                </div> 
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-input data-field="cornerCost" class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Corner Cost:" variant="label-stacked" type="number" formatter="currency" value={cornerCost} disabled ></lightning-input></div>                              
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Select" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Letter Code" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Description" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Price/SqFt" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Booth #" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Depth" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Width" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Total SqFt" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9 slds-p-bottom_small">
                                    <div style="font-weight:bold"><lightning-formatted-text value="Total Booth Cost" ></lightning-formatted-text></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <template iterator:it={products}>
                                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" key={it.value.LWC_Generated_ID__c}>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input data-name={it.value.elementId} name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Select" type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-horizontal_x-small">    
                                            <lightning-input name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Letter Code" value={it.value.Product2.Letter_Code__c} variant="label-hidden" disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Description" value={it.value.Product2.Description} variant="label-hidden" disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Price/SqFt" value={it.value.Product2.Price__c} max-length="3" type="number" formatter="currency" variant="label-hidden" disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input data-name={it.value.elementId} name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Booth Number" value={it.value.Booth_Number__c} max-length="3" type="number" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange} disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input data-name={it.value.elementId} name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Depth" value={it.value.Depth__c} max-length="3" type="number" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange} disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input data-name={it.value.elementId} name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Width" value={it.value.Width__c} max-length="3" type="number" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange} disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Total SqFt" value={it.value.Total_SqFt__c} max-length="3" type="number" variant="label-hidden" disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-9">
                                        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                            <lightning-input name={it.value.Id} class="slds-p-bottom_medium" label="Total Booth Cost" value={it.value.Total_Booth_Cost__c} max-length="4" type="number" formatter="currency" variant="label-hidden" disabled></lightning-input>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </template>                            
                        </div>                        
                    </article>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={closeModal}>Cancel</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleSave} disabled={saveDisabled}>Save</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: try removing slds-size_1-of-9 like this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/QUvrTS_S/2/edit   is this what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of columns available in the responsive grid is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 12. So, 1-of-9 is not going to get a width.

You can learn more in the blueprint documentation: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/